# How to plot the sum and the individual components in Graphite?

Tags: graphite

We collect CPU-time statistics for each host here:

- stats.*hostname*.cpu.system
- stats.*hostname*.cpu.user
- stats.*hostname*.cpu.waiting

How can I plot their sum with individual components shown in different colors? Something like this:
[image: Combined CPU chart example]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, adding `areaMode=stacked` to the URL seems to do the trick...

Still would like a Graphite-expert to comment -- a surprising shortage of them here.